# What makes a terminator a cyborg?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator, cyborg

I was always under the impression that a cyborg was a being, partially robotic partially flesh. Wikipedia backs me up [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyborg):

> A cyborg, short for "*cybernetic organism*", is a being with both biological and artificial (e.g. electronic, mechanical or robotic) parts. The term was coined in 1960 when Manfred Clynes and Nathan S. Kline used it in an article about the advantages of self-regulating human-machine systems in outer space.

In another question & answer session here on SE, a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/t2-could-the-terminator-have-eventually-gotten-mad-or-even-turned-against-john#comment27188_14730) alerted me to the point that Terminator's always refer to themselves as cyborgs. I'm aware they have 'organic disguise layer'. But is that truly enough to consider them cyborgs?

Comment: Check out [the cyborg definition on the Terminator wiki](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Cyborg#Definition).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is the combination of living and mechanical components that makes them cyborgs. The outer-tissue is also interactive with the endoskeleton inside. As the Terminator from Terminator 2 says: “I sense injuries. The data could be called pain.” Implying a bio-mechanical feedback from the skin to the CPU.

The Terminators are also always called cybernetic organisms. 
From the movie transcripts:

[Terminator 1](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/t/terminator-script-transcript-arnold-schwarzenegger.html): Reese: Not a robot. A cyborg - cybernetic organism.

[Terminator 2](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/t2.txt): T-8xx: I'm a cybernetic organism.  Living tissue over a metal endoskeleton.

[Terminator 3](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/t/terminator-3-script-transcript-schwarzenegger.html): T-8xx: T-X is designed to terminate other cybernetic organisms.

Terminators that would be considered cyborgs would be:

- T-8xx series.
- Marcus Wright (T-RIP / T-700 / Hybrid Models)
- Cameron Phillips (series TOK715?)

[Cameron Phillips](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Cameron) (from the Sarah Connor Chronicles) is the only Terminator to ever be shown to eat something. She also had functioning tearducts, and can *feel* heat and wind on her skin.

While they have blood and skin it isn't the same as normal human tissue. In the Sarah Connor Chronicles and Terminator Salvation there is a comment that the Terminator's flesh heals at a much quicker rate than normal humans. [Cromartie](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Cromartie) is also shown to have procured eyes from a living person. He was not able to artificially make eyes for his outer-layer.

In contrast the following Terminators are not considered to be cyborgs:

- T-1
- T-600
- T-1000 / T-1001
- T-X

Comment: Actually, there is a deleted scene from the first Terminator movie in which the Terminator eats a chocolate bar...  Without removing the wrapper first.  So he eats, but he's really stupid.

Comment: @WadCheber: *or* the wrapper also contains essential Terminator nutrients! It could be as much as 60% of his recommended daily aluminium.

Comment: Don't forget the T-1000000 from the theme park attraction! Definitely not a cyborg.

Comment: But doesn't the T-1000 and T-X need an outer tissue of skin to make use of the time displacement unit?

Comment: @jim the time displacement device seems ro be easily fooled "eh, you look human enough, Next!"

Answer (score 18):

The skin isn't the only organic part to certain models. I managed to find this from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_%28character_concept%29#Organic_covering), cited from a [novelised-script](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Terminator_Treatment.txt) that pre-dates the first film:

> "It's called a cyborg really.  Cybernetic organism.  A
>   machine put together with a living thing.  The skin, and
>   some layers under it, the hair, the surface of the eyes,
>   and the inside of the mouth... all that stuff's human
>   tissue, genetically designed for the cyborgs.  But
>   underneath it's all steel and titanium.  Hydraulic
>   actuators instead of muscles.  Controlled by a
>   microcomputer.  It has to eat and breathe to keep the skin
>   alive, though a lot less than us... and there's a little
>   tiny heart and internal organs about the size of a
>   chicken's in a recessed compartment."

As unlikely as it sounds, each T-8* series seems to have tiny organs just for the skin.

I don't think the other models without skin count as cyborgs though.

Comment: That wasn't part of the first three movies though, right?

Comment: @Wikis I think given more production time etc. it could have been.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why the others here that said the same thing as I'm about to say gained negativity, but it *doesn't* matter what they call Terminators in the movies if you want to know what they really are defined as in real life.

A **cyborg** is born human (or other living species) that was turned cybernetic whether the changes were small or completely changing of the living being into a robot. An **android** was *not* born human, is *not* living truly real "life," and is a robot built to resemble and act as if they were a living species like humans.

^That's how it is in most modern pop-culture.

In Terminator they are defined as cyborgs. In real life by real common-use, anything like them would usually be referred to as androids, or simply robots because there isn't any real good definitive line as to when a robot can also be considered human-like enough to also be an android.

Comment: Where is this definition sourced from?

Comment: You are absolutely right, the term "cyborg" was coined in a context of space exploration as a human, whose body was extended with mechanical parts in order to survive in extreme conditions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyborg#Origins

Answer (score 2):

A cyborg is a living biological entity with artificial parts which is therefore has a enhanced with there abilities are basically mechanical or electronic devices, also a human with a bionic implants or mechanical body parts.

An android is a artificial created being in human form that is made to resembling a human with  skin covered an organic materials.

The Terminator is not a cyborg, in other hand is basically an android that moves usually an animatronic or self-moving machine to sent him off an mission to kill sarah connor.

Comment: Data from Star Trek was an Android, because he resembled a human but had no living components. The Borg are cyborg (along with flesh covered Terminators) because they integrate organic matter with robotics.

Comment: No, the Terminator **is** a cyborg, which is why an actual Terminator says "I'm a **CYBERNETIC ORGANISM - LIVING TISSUE OVER A METAL ENDOSKELETON**"

Comment: Daleks and Cybermen have a lot in common, since they are both cyborgs.

Answer (score 0):

Terminators are androids, not cyborgs. Terminators are the killing machines with living tissue over robotic endoskeleton with organic marital. Cyborgs are living organisms with a robotic or mechanical parts. Androids are robots that are made to look and act like human beings or a human-like characteristic in form.

Comment: Except by the terminators admission it's a cyborg...

Comment: I like the way you say that Terminators don't know what they are.  An actual Terminator says "I'm a **CYBERNETIC ORGANISM - LIVING TISSUE OVER A METAL ENDOSKELETON**"

Comment: @WadCheber yeah a *Cyb*ernetic *Org*anism.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage you understand that even Terminators can be mistaken or mislead, especially when they are figments of scenarist's imagination, right?

Comment: @eugenekr I'm not sure what you're saying or getting at?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I mean that Terminator's admission that he was a cyborg did not mean anything. It was written by a scenarist (maybe Cameron himself) who seemingly did not know for sure who cyborgs were. Or maybe in earlier version of scenario Terminator was a cyborg (a human with mechanical body parts) and that phrase was just a leftover which was not cleaned up.

Comment: @eugenekr do you mean a screenwriter? Everything in the film is written by a screenwriter. We can't dismiss everything written by them, or else we'd have nothing to go on.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Yes, a screenwriter. We certainly should not dismiss everything written by them, on the other hand they are not very credible source of information.